# How to set Time Limit on Comment Edit

Tags: 7, nodes, comments

I need to set time limit to edit comment, like Stack Overflow strategy that sets 5 minutes time limit. The [Time Limit on Comment Edit](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/109965/time-limit-on-comment-edit) asked the same question and the [Edit Limit](https://drupal.org/project/edit_limit) was proposed.

In `admin/people/permissions` I allow authenticated users to *Edit own comments* and also Installed Edit Limit module. This is the configuration

[image]

Despite of letting the contents to be editable in 3 minutes, Users are still unable to edit their own comment right after sending their comments. What is the problem? Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

On my site, all I have to do to make this work is to enable the permission  "Edit own comments" for the role, and set the time limit.  If you've done this, it should work.  This is how it looks like when working:

[image]

The only thing I can suggest is that you go over your settings again.

Comment: In the first line of the second paragraph I said that I already did this

Comment: My website is multilingual, After switching to the English I saw the edit link is backed. sounds the problem is with other languages. Thanks anyway

Comment: Why the edit link is not appearing for other languages? I checked the RTL languages

Comment: This looks like a bug. It works fine for me, but I am not using it on any multilingual sites. If you're unable to make it work for other languages than English a multilingual site, you should post a bug report in the project's [issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/edit_limit).